# Why isn't my method an option for onClick?

Tags: unity, c#

Update: The problem went away when I restarted Unity and tried again.

**The problem**

I am using Unity 2019.1.8f1 Personal with Visual Studio for Mac 7.8.4. I have a button named `Refresh`; I would like its `onClick` handler to be the public instance method `Refresh()` in the class `Libretto`. My `GameView` has the `Libretto` script as a component:

[image: screenshot of Inspector view]

The script `Libretto.cs` includes:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Assertions;

public class Libretto : MonoBehaviour, IInputHandler
{

    // Other members omitted

    public void Refresh()
    {
        // Code omitted
    }
}
```

My scene `Scene_Libretto` has a `Canvas` that contains a `Button` named `Refresh`:

[image: Hierarchy view of Scene_Libretto]

In the `onClick()` section of the `Refresh` component, I selected `GameView`, which is a `GameObject`:

[image: Select object window, with GameView selected]

When I try setting the function, the method `Libretto.Refresh()` is not an option:

[image: Dropdown listing Libretto members, not including Refresh()]

**Attempted solutions**

Searching online, I have found these solutions, none of which work for me:

1. The method must be public. (It is.)
2. The method must be void with 0 or 1 parameters. (It is void with 0 parameters.)
3. The script should contain `using UnityEngine.UI;` (It does.)
4. Try creating a new object with just the script and use that. (This makes no difference.)
5. Your code must compile with no errors. (It does.)

**Full project**

I have tried to make my question complete, but, if anyone wants to look at my code, it is available on GitHub in [espertus/UnityWordGames](https://github.com/espertus/UnityWordGames/tree/7510131796e510e36a00f78b29e695f71f68dae3) (a fork of Roger Engelbert's code from his book *Word Games With Unity*).

A sibling scene, `Scene_Crossing`, in the same project has a similar `Refresh` button and `Refresh()` method that work properly.

**Update**

It worked after I restarted Unity.

Comment: What is IInputHandler?

Comment: @SaadAnees It's an interface within the project. It's also implemented in the sibling project that doesn't have the problem I describe.

Comment: The github link you shared is the working one. Can we have your project? And canyou comfirm you are assigning gameobject from scene but not the project folder?

Comment: @SaadAnees Thank you for looking at GitHub. The GitHub link (I tested it in incognito mode) is to my repo (I'm espertus). I created `GameView` (and `EmptyGameObject` for attempted solution 4) from the Hierarchy view with `Scene_Libretto` open.

Comment: I created new empty GameObject, then I attached Crossing.cs to GameObject. Then I dragged that GameObject and assigned to Refresh gameobject with `OnClick` and I can select `Refresh()` method from function list.

Comment: @SaadAnees I'll try that in a fresh clone.

Comment: Make a video of every step and post here. So we will understand better

Comment: @SaadAnees It now works just as it should. I think something I did (such as restarting Unity) triggered a rebuild. If you know a reliable way of causing a rebuild (or want to suggest restarting Unity), I'll happily accept that as an answer.